# Warning : unresponsive script error in jQuery Validation Plugin

Tags: jquery, ajax, validation, jquery-plugins

I am adding a bunch of textboxes and select dropdown using ajax in my form.
You can say add row type functionality.

When I submit the form that time its going to validate via jQuery Validation Plug in.But I face my browser hang for after some moments and show alert box.

My validation code is here:

```
$( "#bookingadd" ).validate({    
  submitHandler: function (form){ 
      $('input[type=text]').each(function(){
        $(this).rules( "add", "required");
      });

      $('select').each(function(){
        $(this).rules( "add", "selectsubservices"); // value is not 0
      });

     jQuery("#bookingadd").submit();

  } });
```

I added [alert box snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkgzC.png)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because you're creating an infinite loop by submitting the form again within the submission handler. To fix this, call the `submit` event on the native `form` element, like this:

```
$("#bookingadd").validate({    
    submitHandler: function(form) { 
        $('input[type=text]').each(function() {
            $(this).rules( "add", "required");
        });

        $('select').each(function() {
            $(this).rules("add", "selectsubservices"); // value is not 0
        }); // < missing } here

        form.submit(); // note use of 'form' here
    } 
});
```

https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#validate-options

Comment: I assume you mean the `}`? The important part of my code which fixes the problem is the `form.submit()`.

Comment: I mean that the part of my code which fixes your problem is changing `jQuery("#bookingadd").submit();` to `form.submit()`

Comment: First of all thanks for replaying me.....
I am doing code as per your answer, but now I am facing new issue that is error will not produce on my first click it produce on second click.